# Boolean Operations with Imported STLs

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm trying to do a Boolean Difference operation between 2 STL files I am importing. The operation doesn't complete properly, not subtracting all of the area. However, if I were to create an object in Blender itself then there is no issue subtracting away from the imported STL.

Is there a way to use one STL to subtract from another STL?
or
Is there a way to easily create a part in Blender from an STL (the geometry would be fairly complex in some instances)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the different options in the _Boolean_ modifier? Switching the _Solver_ between _Fast_ and _Exact_ and in the _Solver Options_ enabling _Self Intersection_ and/or _Hole Tolerant_? Would you mind sharing screenshots, for example of the STL meshes and your modifier settings? The only thing I can imagine is, depending on where you got the STLs from, there is messy geometry, non-manifold geometry or other things that do not work well with the _Boolean_ modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've managed to get it to work now. I believe it was mesh errors in one of the STL files that was causing the issue.